# No strict search using nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have this data on database , I want that if user search the "ja" the result will display both "james" and "jam"

```
  async getUsername(searchname){
    let result = await Database.getConnection().models.User.findAll({ 
      where: { 
        FirstName: searchname
      },
      raw: true
    });
    
    return result;
  },
```

data

```
{
  Firstname: "james",
  ....,
},
{
  Firstname: "jam",
  ....,
},
{
  Firstname: "Harltan",
  ....,
},
{
  Firstname: "Hames",
  ....,
}
```

the current result is either i type or search the ja, no result found, but if i search jam the "jam" data is display

the db i use is mysql

Comment: Is this Mongoose/Mongodb?

Comment: the db i use is mysql

Comment: There is not enough context to answer this. It's hard to tell what the `Database` package capabilities are. It might be possible to have a function `startsWith` or even the `find` method has a field that allows you to do that.

Comment: You can use Regex with this. I don't know how you're accessing your DB or what client library you're using so I can't elaborate with an example.

Comment: Are you using Sequelize?

Comment: @Phil yes, I use Sequelize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/), you can simply use the `startsWith` operator

```js
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

// ...

let result = await Database.getConnection().models.User.findAll({ 
  where: { 
    FirstName: {
      [Op.startsWith]: searchname
    },
  },
  raw: true,
});
```

See the [Operators](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The range of search [operators](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators) available in Sequelize v6 are

```
      [Op.like]: '%hat',                       // LIKE '%hat'
      [Op.notLike]: '%hat',                    // NOT LIKE '%hat'
      [Op.startsWith]: 'hat',                  // LIKE 'hat%'
      [Op.endsWith]: 'hat',                    // LIKE '%hat'
      [Op.substring]: 'hat',                   // LIKE '%hat%'
      [Op.iLike]: '%hat',                      // ILIKE '%hat' (case insensitive) (PG only)
      [Op.notILike]: '%hat',                   // NOT ILIKE '%hat'  (PG only)
      [Op.regexp]: '^[h|a|t]',                 // REGEXP/~ '^[h|a|t]' (MySQL/PG only)
      [Op.notRegexp]: '^[h|a|t]',              // NOT REGEXP/!~ '^[h|a|t]' (MySQL/PG only)
      [Op.iRegexp]: '^[h|a|t]',                // ~* '^[h|a|t]' (PG only)
      [Op.notIRegexp]: '^[h|a|t]',             // !~* '^[h|a|t]' (PG only)
```

The search for strings starting with your search as your example

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize")

let result = await Database.getConnection().models.User.findAll({ 
  where: { 
    FirstName: {
      [Op.startsWith]: searchname,
    }
  },
  raw: true
});
```